Is there a specific way to change the string of a Text View when calling from an ObservableObject in another thread?
In my app, I am uploading a file to my server from my ObservableObject (HTTPHandler). The published strings from HTTPHandler are used by the view (UploadTemplate) to convey status and errors.
HTTPHandler, which also handles all my HTTP needs, is obviously thrown off the main queue.
So essentially the view UploadTemplate has Text views which use the string from HTTPHandler.status to keep the user informed of progress.
While everything works without error, if I do not use DispatchQueue.main.async for every change to the Published strings in HTTPHandler, then I get the purple warning:

Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure
to publish values from the main thread (via operators like
receive(on:)) on model updates.

Is this the way it has to be, or have I missed some step that would not require me to use DispatchQueue being used on so many lines?
import SwiftUI

struct UploadTemplate: View {
    @StateObject var xFile              = XFile()
    @EnvironmentObject var xUser        : XUser
    @State var isShowingDocumentPicker  = false
    @State var error                    = "no error"
    @State var isPerformingURL          = false
    @State var currentStatus            = ""
    @StateObject var httpHandler            = HTTPHandler()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack {
                Color.teal
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                VStack{
                    Text(xFile.fileName.isEmpty ? "No File Selected" : xFile.fileName)

                    Text(httpHandler.statusMsg)

                    Text(httpHandler.errorMsg)

                    
                    Button {
                        isShowingDocumentPicker = true
                    } label: {
                        Text("Select File")
                    }
                    .disabled(isPerformingURL)
                    
                    Button {
                        Task {
                            isPerformingURL = true
                            xFile.fileStage = .uploadOriginal
                            let request = xFile.makePostRequest(xUser: xUser, script: "uploadOrig.pl")
                            var result = await httpHandler.asyncCall(request: request, xFile: xFile)
                        }
                    }
                label: {
                    Text("Upload")
                }
                .disabled((xFile.fullPath.isEmpty || isPerformingURL))
                    
                }
                .navigationTitle("Upload Template")
                .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
            }
            .fileImporter(
                isPresented: $isShowingDocumentPicker,
                allowedContentTypes: [.spreadsheet, .commaSeparatedText], allowsMultipleSelection: false) { result in
                    switch result {
                    case .success(let file):
                        xFile.fillXFile(fileURL: file[0], xUser: xUser)
                        
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}







class HTTPHandler: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    @Published var statusMsg    = ""
    @Published var stage = FileStage.makeTicket
    @Published var errorMsg = ""
    
    func asyncCall(request: URLRequest, xFile: XFile) async -> Int {
        
        do {
            let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
            else {

                DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
                    statusMsg = "Unknown Error 1"
                }

                return 1
            }
            
            if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                if xFile.jsonAndXFile(data: data) {
                    if xFile.hData.status == "SUCCESS" &&
                        xFile.hData.returnvalue == "SSFILEUPLOADED" {
                        xFile.fileStage = .converting
                        DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in statusMsg = "Converting"}
                    } else if xFile.hData.status == "SUCCESS" &&
                        xFile.hData.returnvalue == "SSCONVERTING" {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in statusMsg = String(format: "Converting %@%%", xFile.hData.message)}
                    } else if xFile.hData.status == "SUCCESS" &&
                        xFile.hData.returnvalue == "SSSTAGE1" {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in statusMsg = String(format: "Converting %@%%", xFile.hData.message)}
                    }
                    } else {


                    DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
                        statusMsg = "JSON err"
                    }


                        return 4
                    }
                } else {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
                    statusMsg = String(format: "URL error: %d", httpResponse.statusCode)}
                    return 3
                }
            } catch {
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
                statusMsg = "async error: 2"}
                return 2
            }
        return 0
    }
    
}


You can use @Observable, which doesn't require the main thread. It's only available iOS 17+ though. If you want to support lower versions, what you are doing is fine.

In this case you will need to ensure that you are consistently modifying your @State properties on the main thread in order to resolve the warnings. A comment on your question mentioned using @Observable which won't necessarily resolve the fact that you'll still have contention for @State mutations if you don't synchronize the values onto the @MainActor (or use some other form of synchronization).

Relatedly, consider migrating your network calls to the async/await variants as they'll play much more nicely with the various SwiftUI idioms and you'll have clearer logical flow in the networking implementation.
